# Visual Studio Code Maven for Java Background process terminated with code 255

Tags: spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, Dependencies are not loaded. It gives this error in spring-boot.[error on dependencies charge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAOjf.jpg)[Maven tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFK6f.jpg) When i do mvn spring-boot:run of the back this error occurs[Error visual studio code spring-boot run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jnjY.jpg).
It only happens in this project, in the others it works. Any other clone repository works.

What can I do to get the back to start?